# Android TextView with button to the right

Tags: android, layout

hi i have a text view and i want to show a button right to it. But layout_width="match_parent" pushed the button out of view... how can i tell android to use the space remaining without the button?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:hint="@string/possibility"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

did the Trick

Comment: i must wait until tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

By defining "match_parent", it takes the layout_width of its parent and you have defined "fill_parent" for the parent, so your EditText has "fill_parent" property.

That's why your button is going out of view. If you are not giving weights to your widgets in a linear layout, go with "wrap_content" for `layout_width` of your edittext

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/possibility"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remove"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```